# Increasing Google Analytics API Quota

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-developers-console

Our organization is approaching the hard limits for the Google Analytics API (10000 profile access/day). Google clearly indicates that they will not increase this.

> [Analytics API quota request form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1TUPt4LGXbOAqkYe4hYj_s-KPyhUDuJXdTt1lLihNOeg/viewform?entry.1000000=zend_bi@groupon.jp&entry.1000001=79258572402)
>
> Quotas that CANNOT be increased:
>   -- Per view (profile) limit of 10,000 requests/day  [403 Error with Message about Profile limit: dailyLimitExceeded]

There is a [Google Analytics Premium](http://www.google.dk/analytics/premium/)  for 150 000USD a year but that is much more that we can afford for such a service.

Is there no middle ground for a paid increase to the Google Analytics API quotas?

Comment: You should contact Google's customer or sales support for that.

Comment: @simbabque There is no Google Analytics customer sales or support for free accounts the support is here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @DaImTo this reminds me of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296893/more-actively-discourage-product-support-at-stack-overflow. While technical help is fine, asking for different plans are very likely off-topic here.

Comment: So if we change the question to "how can we increase the Quota, or how can I program around it?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to increase the 10,000 request per profile / view limit. Even if you have a premium Google analytics account that wont change.

What you do get with a Premium analytics account is the option to use BigQuery with Google Analytics making this problem go away.

Option make a second profile / view for the web property you get another 10k that way.